# ORMLite Foreign Collection of abstract class

Tags: java, android, foreign-keys, abstract-class, ormlite

I have 4 classes:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "bucket")
public class Bucket {
    ...
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private Collection<Good> goods;
    ...
}

public abstract class Good {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Bucket bucket;
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "bread")
public class Bread extends Good {
    ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "milk")
public class Milk extends Good {
    ...
}
```

So, inside `Bucket` I have `ForeignCollectionField` of abstract class `Good`, which, of course, doesn't have its own database table.

Database entries are created normally, but when i try to call `queryForAll()` it gives me error:

```
bucketDao.queryForAll(); 
// no such table: good (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `basecard` WHERE `bucket_id` = ?
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Or I can't even create ForeignCollectionField of abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

I found it pretty simple to solve this problem.

I just removed `@ForeignCollectionField` from `Bucket` model at all. So, Inside `Bucket` table ORMLite knows nothing about `Good` entity.

**Persist data:**

```
// 1 using bucketDao add bucket
bucketDao.add(bucket)
// 2 iterate over collection
for (Bread bread: breadList) {
  bread.setBucket(bucket); // set current bucket to good item
  breadDao.add(bread); // using breadDao add bread
}
// 3 do the same with milk collection
for (Milk milk: milkList) {
  milk.setBucket(bucket);
  milkDao.add(milk);
}
```

**Load data:**

```
int bucketId = 1; // for example working with bucket with id=1
Bucket bucket = bucketDao.queryForEq("id", bucketId)); // query for this bucket
List<Milk> milkList = milkDao.queryForEq("bucket_id", bucketId); // query for all milks, that has a foreign key to current bucket
List<Break> breadList = breadDao.queryForEq("bucket_id", bucketId); // the same for bread

// finally set milks and breads to Good collection inside Bucket
List<Good> goodList = new ArrayList<>();   
goodList.addAll(milkList);   
goodList.addAll(breadList);   
bucket.setGoods(goodList);
```